# Make border block for element in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my code to make spaceship move using arrow-key and I need to block moving this elements(spaceship) from out the page range?

I mean when press down key the element make go to down I don't need that please this is my code:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    $("body").innerWidth()
    switch (e.which){
    case 37:    //left arrow key
        $(".box").finish().animate({
            left: "-=50"
        });
        break;
    case 38:    //up arrow key
        $(".box").finish().animate({
            top: "-=50"
        });
        break;
    case 39:    //right arrow key
        $(".box").finish().animate({
            left: "+=50"
        });
        break;
    case 40:    //bottom arrow key
        $(".box").finish().animate({
            top: "+=50"
        });
        break;
    }
```

css :

```
.box{
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    width: 130px;
    height: 130px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 200px auto 0;
    background: url("http://davidpapp.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/rocket.png") ;
}
```

Comment: What habe you tried? I don't see an attempt at solving your issue in your code example.

Comment: i dont now how i can make my page "Flexible" - if you are try my code you should now what i mean ( The page expands )

Comment: Hi @HeroGuevara, you want spaceship not to move outside page width right??

Comment: Yes, that's what I want please help me and save my day

Answer (score 1):

Take a moment to review the logic of your script. When the button is pressed, it just moves the objects regardless of its location on the page. Instead, you should include a conditional to check whether it *can/should* move before performing the actual move.

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    var width = $("body").innerWidth();//Assigned this value to a variable
    var height = $('body').height();//Created a variable for the height
    var $box = $('.box');//Because I hate typing this so many times
    var posX = parseFloat($box.css('left'));
    var posY = parseFloat($box.css('top'));
    switch (e.which) {
        case 37:    //left arrow key
            //Don't allow if moving to the left would cause it to go less than 0
            if(posX - 50 >= 0) {
                $box.finish().animate({
                    left: "-=50"
                });
            }
            break;
        case 38:    //up arrow key
            //Don't allow if moving up would cause it to go less than 0
            if(posY - 50 >= 0) {
                $box.finish().animate({
                    top: "-=50"
                });
            }
            break;
        case 39:    //right arrow key
            //Not only checking to make sure the origin doesn't go over the width
            //but also keep the width of the box in mind so it appears to stay within bounds
            if(posX + 50 + $box.width() <= width) {
                $box.finish().animate({
                    left: "+=50"
                });
            }
            break;
        case 40:    //bottom arrow key
            //Not only checking to make sure the origin doesn't go past the bottom line
            //but also keep the height of the box in mind so it appears to stay within bounds
            if(posY + 50 + $box.height() <= height) {
                $box.finish().animate({
                    top: "+=50"
                });
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

P.S. I wrote this pretty quickly and without testing, so don't be surprised if I made a spelling error or have a less than sign and greater than sign mixed up, haha. I hope you understand the logic I'm trying to convey, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Below code to show what to do. You can tweak the numbers though

```js
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    $("body").innerWidth()
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight;
    var offset = $(".box").offset();
    switch (e.which){
     case 37:
        if(offset.left>=50)
        $(".box").finish().animate({
            left: "-=50"
        });
        break;
    case 38:
        if(offset.top>=100)
        $(".box").finish().animate({
            top: "-=50"
        });
        break;
    case 39:    //right arrow key
        if(offset.left+130+50 < width)
        $(".box").finish().animate({
            left: "+=50"
        });
        break;
    case 40:    //bottom arrow key
      if(offset.top+50 < height)
        $(".box").finish().animate({
            top: "+=50"
        });
        break;
    }      
   
   })
```

```css
body{

 }


 .box{
     position: relative;
     top: 10px;
     width: 130px;
     height: 130px;
     position: relative;
     margin: 200px auto 0;
     background: url("http://davidpapp.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/rocket.png") ;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
```